# Archived Posts in Wrong Category

Tags: posts, categories

I am working on a site and am having an issue with one of the categories. There is plenty of content on the site and there are seven different categories. All of the categories display the correct posts except for the very last one. I've searched all around and have not seen this exact issue come up (oftentimes, people just have the wrong posts in all their categories).

Please see the URL I'm working with. It is http://www.glossandglam.com/blog/ and the category that is not working is "Tutorials." Thanks for any help you can provide.

### EDIT

Here is code for more detail:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<ul style="list-style-type:none;">

<?php

if ($paged == 0)
  $offset = 0;
else
  $offset = ($paged - 1) * 11;
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 11, 'offset' => $offset, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);

?>


<li id="category_li">
    <div id="image_con">
        <div id="image_recent">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 200 );
the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cr_content">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="gloss_glam_font"> <?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="excerpt_cat"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div id="clearfix">
    </div>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

A quick explanation is that we are displaying 11 posts per page with a custom pagination at the bottom. I am using the "Category Post List Widget" plugin to style the list items that are being generated.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing any code. The "tutorials" archive index appears to be displaying posts from other categories. Are you modifying the query directly (e.g. via `query_posts()`) anywhere? Do you have a customized loop in one of your template files?

Comment: I will add my customized loop. One sec. Thanks for getting this started.

Comment: Alright, I've added more code above.

Comment: What template file is this? Or, in what template file is this loop code called? Also: why are you hacking up the loop query this much, just to get 11 posts per page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost assuredly your custom loop.

I am guessing that this is your problem:

```
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
```

Further, I'm guessing that the `$post` object being queried here has more than one category term defined. Thus, `$category[0]` is returning something *other* than "tutorials".

Easiest solution: ensure all posts only have one category term defined.

More complex, but more future-proof and stable, solution: eliminate the use of the Category Post List Widget Plugin, go back to using the default query loop, and define your markup/style as necessary for your archive index pages.

Comment: Ok great, thank you. You've nailed it without me even telling you all the details. I'm still learning all of this and I appreciate your help!

Comment: One more question Chip. Is there any way you could point me in the right direction to get back to the default query loop for an archive page? I've gotten myself so far from the default that I'm having a hard time getting back to the start. Thanks again.

Comment: And the reason I was using the long code was that I was having trouble doing pagination with the post query. I figured I'd just have the page pull the posts according to the page number of the archive it was on. I suppose there is a simpler way to do it?

Comment: I'd be happy to! You might want to open a new question, asking specifically what you need. Perhaps something like, "How to modify the loop to have 11 posts per page", and then provide details in the question (such as: only for category archive index pages, etc.). I would normally suggest editing *this* question, but really, they're two completely different types of questions.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was considering that because I didn't want you or someone else to help me without getting credit. I'll post the link when I have it up. Thanks!

Comment: Ehh... it's not about getting credit, but rather about ensuring that the Questions and Answers are clear, distinct, and useful as a knowledge base. :)

Comment: You are correct (and a hero haha)! Here's the link to the new question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63424/how-to-modify-the-loop-in-archives-php-to-have-11-posts-per-page-and-css-styling