# How To Modify The Loop in archives.php To Have 11 Posts Per Page and CSS Styling

Tags: categories, query-posts, archives

I edited my loop in archives.php in order to work with pagination and with the Category Post List Widget. I basically pieced it all together from random code and ideas and am now so far from the default post query that I'm having trouble getting back to square one. The reason I need to get back to square one is that I need two things:

1) My code is messing up my category posts when the post has two category tags. When that happens, they get placed in the wrong categories (or don't get placed at all).

2) By doing this custom coding, I lost the query for 'tags' as well so the tag pages don't work correctly.

I need to get back to square one so I can set up tags and category posts to be displayed correctly but within the correct `<li>`s that I style. I'm not sure if I even need the Category Post List widget anymore because, if I'm not mistaken, I can call the `set_post_thumbnail_size();`, `the_title();`, `the_excerpt()`, etc. without the widget and just style my own list items.

Anyhow, here's the code I've got, I imagine I need to scrub a bunch of it to get back where I need to go. Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<ul style="list-style-type:none;">

<?php
if ($paged == 0)
  $offset = 0;
else
  $offset = ($paged - 1) * 11;
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 11, 'offset' => $offset, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>


<li id="category_li">
    <div id="image_con">
        <div id="image_recent">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 200 );
the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cr_content">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="gloss_glam_font"> <?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <hr>
    <div class="excerpt_cat"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div id="clearfix">
    </div>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>


<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>
    <?php else :

        if ( is_category() ) { // If this is a category archive
        printf("<div class='post-content'><p><em><strong>Not Found:</strong> Sorry, but there aren't any posts in the &middot;<strong>%s</strong>&middot; category yet.</em></p></div>", single_cat_title('',false));
    } else if ( is_date() ) { // If this is a date archive
        echo("<div class='post-content'><p><em><strong>Not Found:</strong> Sorry, but there aren't any posts with this date.</em></p></div>");
    } else if ( is_author() ) { // If this is a category archive
        $userdata = get_userdatabylogin(get_query_var('author_name'));
        printf("<div class='post-content'><p><em><strong>Not Found:</strong> Sorry, but there aren't any posts by &middot;<strong>%s</strong>&middot; yet.</em></p></div>", $userdata->display_name);
    } else {
        echo("<div class='post-content'><p><em>No posts found.</em></p></div>");
    }

endif; ?>
```

### EDIT

Alright, I edited it and I can't figure out where I'm off. I'm using my tag.php template as an example here (not the category.php). Here's what I've done so far (based off the code provided by Chip in the answers):

```
function wpse63424_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_main_query() ) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        if ( is_category() || is_tag() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page',11 );
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse63424_filter_pre_get_posts' );

$tag = get_query_var('tag');
$myposts = get_posts('tag__in' => array($tag));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
```

My thinking was that I've set a filter of 11 posts per page, I query for a specific tag, set the posts to the tag in that array and then set up the posts accordingly. When I just run get_posts(); it returns 11 posts per page unfiltered so I know that Chip's code works fine. I guess I'm not understanding how the functions are called correctly yet...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, for layout and CSS styling, I would recommend creating *template files* for the contexts you want to customize; i.e. create a `category.php` and a `tag.php` for the category and tag index archive pages, respectively. In either case, copy `archive.php` (or, if it doesn't exist, copy `index.php`), and rename the copy as `category.php`. Then, modify the markup as necessary.

For CSS, ensure that you're using `body_class()` in your Theme, and then you can use the *category and tag-based [CSS classes applied to the `<body>` tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Default_Values).

The next step is customizing the query to output 10 posts per page, instead of 10, for category/tag archive index pages. For that, use the `pre_get_posts` filter. Add the following callback and `add_filter()` call to `functions.php`:

```
function wpse63424_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_main_query() ) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        if ( is_category() || is_tag() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page',11 );
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse63424_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

This callback tells WordPress:

1. If the query isn't the *main* query, then return it without modifying it. (This prevents, e.g., Recent Posts widget query, or navigation menus from being impacted.)
2. If the current page is either a category archive index or a tag archive index, change the `'posts_per_page'` query variable to `11`, then return the query.

Comment: Oh wow, great. I have a question before I move forward. With this code, it seems that I wouldn't need to make both a 'category' and a 'tag' template since the conditional has "||" (determining between category and tag there). The CSS styling would be the same for both categories and tags so would you still recommend making two different templates?

Comment: The loop query modification won't change the actual HTML markup. So, if you need to modify HTML markup, you'll need to make those changes directly in the template. Thus the need for both a `category.php` and a `tag.php`. (Or, if you're using a `loop.php` template-part file, create `loop-tag.php` and `loop-category.php`, etc.)

Comment: just another comment: to (re-)build a category archive, don't use `$category = get_the_category($post->ID);` but use `$category = get_query_var('cat');` - `get_the_category()` gets categories of a post which can be random in the category archive if posts have more than one category

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense. I'm about to dive into this, wish me luck!

Comment: I edited my code above to show where I've gotten. I'm trying to query for tags (I'm starting with tags at the moment and will go back to categories). I think I'm close but I'm not sure...

Comment: The callback and `add_action()` call belong in **`functions.php`**, *not* in the **template file**.

Comment: Also: you need to get rid of **all** of your custom loop code. Just use the default loop code for your Theme. Use whatever is in `index.php`, or `loop.php`, or whatever your Theme uses. You don't need to modify the default loop markup in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Oh man, it was way simpler than I was thinking. I see what you were saying, literally just revert back to the original loop and then I can style it accordingly. It was just a matter of putting that function in the functions.php file. Thanks again, you are the man.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if something's changed with the latest version of WP (4.4+), but `is_main_query()` will return a false positive as-is.  It should be:

```
function wpse63424_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        if ( is_category() || is_tag() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page',11 );
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse63424_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```