# How do I override the default number of items to be listed on an archive.php page?

Tags: custom-post-types, archive-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Modify The Loop in archives.php To Have 11 Posts Per Page and CSS Styling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63424/how-to-modify-the-loop-in-archives-php-to-have-11-posts-per-page-and-css-styling)

I am using the following code on my archive.php template to list a few fields from a custom post type. It's an album review post type and this code pulls in the artist name, the album name and the album cover.

Is there any way to alter this code to tell wordpress to display a certain number of results?

The issue I have is that for all other archive pages the default (set to 10) is fine, but because I am only displaying a thumbnail and a name on the archive for reviews there's a lot of room to add more in.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into `pre_get_posts` and modify the query.  Your hooked function will receive a WP_Query object as it's only argument. You can check to see if you're on a the correct post type archive and modify away.

Something like this:

```
<?php
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse63675_pre_posts');
function wpse63675_pre_posts($q)
{
    if(!is_post_type_archive('your_album_type'))
        return;

    $q->set('posts_per_page', 20); // or however many you want
}
```

You can drop the above in your `functions.php` file or a plugin.  Use with caution.

I wrote [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-posts-per-page/) that takes care of this for you.  It does [the above](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/Advanced-Posts-Page/blob/master/inc/front.php#L40), but with a set of fields in the admin area.

Comment: +1 for the plugin and its code. Sidenote: Wouldn't it be better to hook the main file include process in a function hooked on `plugins_loaded`? Don't have to tell you why hooking stuff is a good idea ;)

Comment: That's true.  I tend not hook includes into anything, to be honest: I make assumptions about what classes and functions are available elsewhere in the plugin, and I don't want to check to see if they are there.  Better idea (maybe?):  `if(apply_filters('plugin_enabled_somefeature', true)) { /* load the files for the feature */ }`

Comment: Hm. Interesting approach. I normally (with everyday stuff), just hook my bootstrap class into `plugins_loaded`. There all the includes happen and if needed, I hook into `init`, as its present during ajax, admin and public requests. Then the routing runs via all the conditional hooks (`load-{$pagehook}` and such) or via conditionals/query args for public requests. So far I've never thought about such an approach, but there're core filters (for e.g. the one on the gallery shortcode cb fn), that behave like switches. Will have to think about this one. If you want to discuss it, reach me via mail.