# Wordpress showing wrong category name

Tags: categories, archives

I'm using:

```
$category = get_the_category();
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
```

to display the current category as a header in an archive template (example of local url is http://imac.local:5757/category/accommodation/, http://imac.local:5757/category/service/ etc)

For the first 3 categories, this works fine, but after that it's showing a child category instead. I've tried changing the slug of the posts *and* the category, updating the permalinks, unpublishing posts in the child category which is showing (it then shows another child category instead) - but none of this solves the problem.

I suppose it's a clash of slugs & permalinks somewhere, but changing these doesn't seem to fix it. Is there more specific wordpress php which can be written to avoid this clashing?

I did find this post: [Archived Posts in Wrong Category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63359/archived-posts-in-wrong-category) but it doesn't seem to be the same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far a I can understand you need to display the category name for the current page when viewing a category page.

You can make use of the query variables to retrieve the category name, for example:

```
$category = get_queried_object('cat'); 
echo $category->name;
```

**EDIT**

A global check to see what is returned by the main query for a specific page/template, you can do a `var_dump` of the main query global, `$wp_query`. Add the following code inside your template outside of the loop

```
?><pre><?php var_dump($wp_query); ?></pre><?php
```

To check which query variables are available on a template/page, you can do a `var_dump` of [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
 var_dump( $queried_object );
```

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables) is also a list of all query variables

Comment: Thanks Pieter - but this doesn't actually show anything at all...

Comment: How does your file structure look like. Are you using custom taxonomies and or custom post types. Do `var_dump($wp_query)` anywhere outside the loop in your template

Comment: Ah yeh - it's a custom post type. Would that make a difference when echoing out the category titles? `var_dump($wp_query)` for `cat` echos out  `["cat"]=> int(6)` - which is actually the ID for the correct category that _should_ be displaying. I think we're onto something here :P

Comment: Please see my updated code

Comment: Hooray! That's perfect - thanks so much. So, I suppose this same method will work for any data outputted in `var_dump($wp_query)`? Replacing `cat` with whatever I need to echo out...?

Comment: Glad it worked. Can see this was a Friday answer ;-). I have added more info in my answer, so check it out. Enjoy of what is left of the weekend. :-)